# Determine whether one string can be made from a subset of characters in another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary where letters correspond to numbers and a string, and seek to return True if each letter occurs in the string a number of times equal to or less than the number associated with that letter in the dictionary. When this problem was less complex and didn't have the limitation of counting occurrences, I used `all(x in string for x in dictionary)`. Is there a similarly concise way to test for this based on the int value in the dictionary?

Edit: Apologies, here's what we're looking at.

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """
    if word.lower() in wordList and all(x in hand for x in word):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This code returns True if *any* instance of the letter in the string appears as a dictionary key of Hand, when I now need it to return False unless the number of times that letter occurs is <= the int-value for that key. I've accomplished this rather messily, and was wondering if there was a way to incorporate that level of specificity into the `all` method or something similarly concise.

Comment: Please provide us with a sample input and an expected output. Your question isn’t complete enough for a definite answer.

Comment: Please post some of your data, and what you'd expect to get from it?

Comment: Sorry, there's the codeblock with docstring

Answer (score 1):

From your docstring, you are trying to determine is whether `word` could be formed using the letters in `hand`. This is extremely straight forward by using `collections.Counter`. You don't even need to make `hand` a dictionary.

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
    wc, hc = Counter(word), Counter(hand)
    return word.lower() in word_list and all(wc[k] <= hc[k] for k in wc)
```

If you want to keep `hand` as a dictionary, just use `hand` instead of `hc` in the final line and omit turning it into a `Counter`.

This isn't optimal in terms of complexity, but the same general idea could be used to write a good algorithm. Note that this is more efficient than using `count` because each string only needs to be iterated over once instead of once for each unique letter.

A more efficient function to check this might look something like:

```
def is_partial_anagram(word, pool):
    pool_counter = Counter(pool)
    for c in word:
        if not pool_counter[c]:
            return False
        pool_counter[c] -= 1
    return True
```

The complexity here is asymptotically the same, but will return `False` sooner when there is no match and avoids builder a `Counter` for `word`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your `hand` dict is formed like:

```
hand = {"f": 1, "o": 2, "b": 1, "a": 1, "r": 1, "z": 0}
```

And you want it to match `foo` and `bar` but not `baz` as `z` is set to `0` and there is at least one `z`. You can do that using `str.count()` like:

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    if word.lower() in wordList and all(hand.get(x, 0) >= word.count(x) for x in set(word)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Not the most efficient but should give you the idea. You can test it with:

```
hand = {"f": 1, "o": 2, "b": 1, "a": 1, "r": 1, "z": 0}  # letters with their allowed counts
word_list = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]  # allowed words

print(isValidWord("foo", hand, word_list))  # True
print(isValidWord("bar", hand, word_list))  # True
print(isValidWord("baz", hand, word_list))  # False
```

Comment: This could be made slightly more concise by omitting `x in hand` and then using `hand.get(x, 0)`.